# UltiSnips regex macthing

Tags: regular-expression, filetype-tex, plugin-ultisnips, filetype-markdown

I want the possibility of transforming an inline equation in latex to a display equation.

So I want `$something$` to become

```
$$
something
$$
```

My attempt was this:

```
snippet "$(.+)$" "whatever" r
$$
\1
$$
$1
endsnippet
```

My understanding is that `(.+)` would match any character 1 or more times (captured in a group), and `\1` would print the match in the group.

I also tried using python interpolation with `!p snip.rv = match.group(1)` to no success either.

Both attempt just lead to a tab inserted. Any ideas?

Comment: I’m not familiar, does ultisnips use vim flavored RegEx? If so `+` needs to be `\+`.

Comment: Ok, I'm stupid..... The 2 "$" in the regex match condition shn ould be escaped
But the \1 doesn't work, the python interpolation does....

Comment: shoot! Happens to the best of us. Welcome to [Vi and Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/)!

Comment: Thanks! Should I delete the question? Seems like it was such a silly mistake (even though I was stuck on it for so long :/)

Comment: If you have an answer, post it. If it’s just a typo that isnt likely to help others, we can close it, but to be honest I wouldn’t have thought of the escape necessarily, so I think it’s worth leaving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of Jake Grossman's comment, I eventually realized the `$` in the regex trigger should be escaped:
(Also had to use python interpolation)

```
snippet "\$(.+)\$" "whatever" r
$$
`!p snip.rv = match.group(1)`
$$
$0
endsnippet
```

The trigger right after `snippet` will match anything between `$` and capture it in a group (with the `()`)

In the python interpolation, `snip.rv` stands for "return value" and the `match.group(1)` prints the first group in the regex (the only one in this case)

Comment: I updated the snippet to use backquotes, I believe that's the correct syntax, no? Also, I think using `$0` at the end (instead of `$1`) is slightly more correct, it indicates where the cursor goes after the snippet ends (rather than a field in the snippet.)

Comment: Did I use a different quote? The edited version in now exactly what I have in my config, so it should be correct, thanks.... I guess the $0  could be better, I'll check latter

Comment: @RicardoKullock you can click "edited ..." to see the history; it looks like the original used `'` instead of backticks

Comment: Changed to use $0 like suggested